# Jssor continuous rotation without stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am using the Jssor slider in a couple areas on my site and would like to continue using it however, in this case I need it to act more like a marquee instead of a slideshow. Is this possible?

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="logo-slide-container">
    <div class="logo-slides" u="slides">
        <div><span u="image"><img id="supplierLogo" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></span></div>
        <div><span u="image"><img id="supplierLogo" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></span></div>
        <div><span u="image"><img id="supplierLogo" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></span></div>
        <div><span u="image"><img id="supplierLogo" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></span></div>
        <div><span u="image"><img id="supplierLogo" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></span></div>
        <div><span u="image"><img id="supplierLogo" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></span></div>
        <div><span u="image"><img id="supplierLogo" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = {
             $AutoPlay: true,
             $PlayOrientation: 2,
             $AutoPlayInterval: 1,
             $SlideDuration: 3500,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
             $DisplayPieces: 5 
    };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("logo-slide-container", options);
});
```

I would like it to continue rotating without pausing, a nice constant scroll. 
Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6qpdyex/3/)** of what I have so far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = {
             $AutoPlay: true,
             $PlayOrientation: 2,
             $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$Linear,         
             $Idle: 0,
             $SlideDuration: 3500, 
             $DisplayPieces: 5
        };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("logo-slide-container", options);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/b6qpdyex/4/